GnuRadio logging pattern
I am wondering if it is possible to change the pattern of GnuRadios logger output to get something like
[HHMMSS][thread] msg...
Gnuradio 3.10 uses spdlog  and in spdlog it’s easy to change the pattern (ref):
  spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S %z] [%n] [%^---%L---%$] [thread %t] %v");

My goal is to change the pattern of the logger in an application that uses GnuRadio-blocks, but I don't know how to make my changes permanent.
Thank you for following my task up to this point.
From now on, let's take a look at my minimal example:

Assuming all relevant dependencies are installed, such as gnuradio-dev.
The minimal example consists of "CMakeLists.txt" and "main.cpp"
The content:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(minimalexample)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


list(APPEND GR_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS RUNTIME PMT BLOCKS)
find_package(Gnuradio "3.10" REQUIRED)
find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)

add_executable(minimalexample main.cpp )
target_link_libraries(minimalexample PRIVATE
        Threads::Threads
        gnuradio-blocks
        gnuradio-pmt
        gnuradio-runtime
        spdlog::spdlog
        spdlog
        fmt)

main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/common.h"
#include <gnuradio/logger.h>
#include "gnuradio/blocks/null_sink.h"
#include "gnuradio/top_block.h"
#include "gnuradio/io_signature.h"

/**
 * the Logger class is a wrapper around the gnu radio logger, my initial idea is to setup the pattern inside the constructor
 * reference: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Logging#Logging_in_C++
 */
class Logger {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<gr::logger> d_logger;;

public:
    Logger(const std::string &name):
        // initializing the d_logger triggers GnuRadio to set a static default pattern
        // (reference: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/7bbbeedba2d604dfbf46f0d0e6ef4aadde61c81b/gnuradio-runtime/lib/logger.cc#L97 )
        d_logger(std::make_shared<gr::logger>(name))
    {
        // the command ("set pattern") should result in overwriting the pattern of d_logger
        d_logger->d_logger->set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S %z] [thread %t] %v");
        d_logger->d_logger->debug("Logger initialized");
    }

    ~Logger() {
        d_logger->d_logger->debug("Logger destroyed");
    }

    /** inline function wrapper for warn-logging */
    template<typename... Ts>
    inline void warn(const spdlog::string_view_t &message, const Ts &... args) {
        d_logger->d_logger->warn(message, args...);
    }
};

/**
 * customSource and customSource_impl are like OOT implementation of a dummy processing block
 * (reference: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/BlocksCodingGuide#Coding_Structure)
 */
class customSource : virtual public gr::sync_block {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<customSource> sptr;
    static sptr make();
};

class customSource_impl : public customSource {
public:
    customSource_impl();
    ~customSource_impl() override;
    int work(int noutput_items, gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items, gr_vector_void_star &output_items) override;
};

customSource::sptr customSource::make() { return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr(new customSource_impl()); }

customSource_impl::customSource_impl(): gr::sync_block("customSource",
                                                       gr::io_signature::make(0, 0, sizeof(gr_complex)),
                                                       gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(gr_complex))) {
    d_logger->info("Custom source initialized");
}

customSource_impl::~customSource_impl() = default;

int customSource_impl::work(int noutput_items,
                            gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
                            gr_vector_void_star &output_items) {
    // empty work routine. Nothing to be done here for minimal example
    return 0;
}

/**
 * the actual main routine:
 * tasks: set up a logger
 */
int main() {
    Logger logger("logger");
    logger.warn("hello from logger {}", "!!! yay !!!");

    const auto src = customSource::make();
    const auto sink = gr::blocks::null_sink::make(sizeof(gr_complex));
    const auto tb = gr::make_top_block("tiny top block");
    tb->connect(src, 0, sink, 0);

    return 0;
}


The Output
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] Logger initialized
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] hello from logger !!! yay !!!
customSource :info: Custom source initialized
logger :debug: Logger destroyed

Process finished with exit code 0


Summary
The expecteted output is
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] Logger initialized
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] hello from logger !!! yay !!!
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] Custom source initialized
[21:04:27 +02:00] [thread 10242] Logger destroyed

If the topblock,customSource etc. are not instantiated, the output is as expected. But when the blocks are there, itseems like GnuRadio is overwriting the pattern somewhere.
My questions are:

where does the pattern reset happen?
how can I change that pattern, so that it is not overwritten.
does my concept make sence, to reuse the gnuradio-logger rather than using the spdlog directly?

Thanks for the advice and your efforts.
